# set dropdownlist selectedIndex in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a grideview that is being populated by an ObjectDataSource. In the EditItemTemplate, I have a dropdownlist which gets populated thru the code behind on the RowDataBound event:

```
 ddStates.DataSource = snm.getStates();
 ddStates.DataTextField = "State";
 ddStates.DataValueField = "StateID";
 ddStates.DataBind();
```

Now, what i would like to do is set the selected index of my dropdownlist to the current value for the row from the objectDataSource.  How do I get the StateID from the ObjectDataSource?

Thanks, I have been running in circles on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always use row's [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) to get the underlying `DataSource`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit))
    {
        // if this doesn't work, use the debugger to get the type of e.Row.DataItem
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        int StateID = row.Field<int>("StateID");
        var ddStates = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddStates");
        ddStates.DataSource = snm.getStates();
        ddStates.DataTextField = "State";
        ddStates.DataValueField = "StateID";
        ddStates.DataBind();
        ddStates.SelectedValue = StateID.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it!  that works!  thank you so much, I was banging my head trying to google the info!